# Array previous values getting overwritten in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to do the following, where foo is a function which fills the 'out' array.
But for each data centre in data centres object, pushed out array is getting overwritten by a new value.

I want to prevent this overwriting. 
How to create a new array reference/ instance in a loop?

```
 _.map(datacenters, function(datacenter){      
        var out = []
        foo(datacenter, out);
        $scope.dcSelected.push(out);
    });
```

Comment: What does `foo()` specifically do? Please show the code.

Comment: foo adds objects into 'out' like out.push(obj1), out.push(obj2), out.push(obj3) etc

Answer (score 1):

Put your `out` declaration outside:

```
var out = [];
_.map(datacenters, function(datacenter){      
    foo(datacenter, out);
    $scope.dcSelected.push(out);
});
```

Comment: I think that is the main reason, plus one!

Comment: @SanketAchari Can you log the results on the console?

Answer (score 0):

You may try angular.copy(out) of angularJs. Hope it ll work for you

```
_.map(datacenters, function(datacenter){      
        var out = []
        foo(datacenter, out);
        $scope.dcSelected.push(angular.copy(out));
    });
```

Comment: tried. but still its overwriting the previous values.

Comment: Because array reference return by foo function that is why value getting overwrite again and again. You should move your code to push data in scope variable $scope.dcSelected.push(local Variable in foo function) in the foo function than definitely it ll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you trying to do, so I will do a general example:

```
var datacenters = [1,2,3,4]

var out = []
datacenters.map(function(datacenter){      

      datacenter2 = datacenter + 1;
      out.push(datacenter2);
  }); 

console.log(out);
```

> [ 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

(I used map that way because I haven't imported the underscore for js)

Answer (score -1):

You have 2 options:

1) create a closure

2) create another array as part of your controller, that will store linkage of data center and out an array, imagine it as a key, value but in a global variable of the same controller.